# Partial and directional derivatives

Tags: analysis

Find an example where partial derivatives exist and there is no directional derivative (in a direction other than $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$).

Find an example where directional derivatives exist in directions other than $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$ and partials do not exist.

Comment: See http://home.iitk.ac.in/~psraj/mth101/lecture_notes/Lecture28.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case, a standard example is
$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ (x, y) \mapsto \begin{cases} \frac{x y}{x^2+y^2} \quad &(x,y) \not= (0,0), \\ 0 \quad \ &(x,y) = (0,0). \end{cases} $$
At the origin there exist no directional derivatives except for multiples of $e_1$ or $e_2$.

For the second case, we can look at 
$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ (x, y) \mapsto \begin{cases} \frac{x + y}{x^2+y^2} \quad &(x,y) \not= (0,0), \\ 0 \quad \ &(x,y) = (0,0). \end{cases} $$
Here you get no directional derivatives at the origin except for multiples of $ \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} $.

Comment: Now it looks good.

Comment: To clean up the thread, I'll delete my comments, and you can do the same.

Comment: Not always, but given that you've made the needed corrections, the prior comments serve no purpose to a future reader.

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider 2D case, define

$f(0,y) = 1 $ for all $y$.

$f(x,0) = 1 $ for all $x$.

$f(x,y) = 0$  otherwise.

Now, consider partial and directional derivatives at the origin.

2. Consider 2D case, define

$f(0,0) = 0 $

$f(0,y) = 1 $ for all $y \neq 0$.

$f(x,0) = 1 $ for all $x \neq 0$.

$f(x,y) = 0$  otherwise.

Now, consider partial and directional derivatives at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, here's a continuous example . . .

Fix a positive integer $n > 1$ and define $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ by 
$
{\displaystyle{f(x)=\!\!\sum_{1\le i < j\le n}\!\!|x_i x_j|^{\frac{1}{3}}}}
$.

At the origin, a directional derivative exists only in a direction along a coordinate axis.